# SURF and Matching with Undistorted Image OpenCV C++

Tags: c++, opencv

i'm working on OpenCV 4 in ROS Melodic. After `undistort()`, images have a black background that is detected by SURF. How can I fix this?
[image]

Comment: you could try to add a border (replicate or mirror) with copyMakeBorder before undistorting, but you might have to change the principal point (last column of the camera matrix) to adjust to the bigger image size and crop the undistorted image. Another way could be to just drop all the keypoints which are too close to the original image border (or even outside of the border). You can create a mask by undistorting a pure white image with same size as your current image.

Comment: Thank you! Can you write the code please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution thanks to Micka's comment. I filtered featurs during lowe ratio test:

```
//-- Filter matches using the Lowe's ratio test
//Default ratio_thresh: 0.7f; 
vector<DMatch> matches;
size_t i = 0;
bool lowe_condition = false;
bool black_background_condition = false;

//Filter matches in black background
for (i; i < knn_matches.size(); i++)
{
    lowe_condition = (knn_matches[i][0].distance < ratio_thresh * knn_matches[i][1].distance);
    black_background_condition = ((keypoints1[i].pt.x >= width_low ) && (keypoints1[i].pt.x <= width_high)) && ((keypoints1[i].pt.y >= height_low ) && (keypoints1[i].pt.y <= height_high));

    if (lowe_condition && black_background_condition)
    {
        matches.push_back(knn_matches[i][0]);
    }
}
```